# @KafkaListener Read from beginning every time

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using the following example to use the spring Kafka consumer to read messages.  My use case requires that every time a message is produced, the listener reads from the beginning, every time.

```
@KafkaListener(
    id = "grouplistener",
    topicPartitions = { 
        @TopicPartition(
            topic = "mycompactedtopic", partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0")
        )
    }
)

public void onReceiving(
    String payload, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Integer offset,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic
) {
    log.info(
        "Processing topic = {}, partition = {}, offset = {}, payload= {}",
        topic, partition, offset, payload
    );
}
```

I can only seem to get it to read from the beginning on application startup and then it normally just consumes messages going forward.

Is there a way to force it to seek to beginning every time?

Comment: Every time a message is sent, you need to reconsume old messages?

Comment: What is the business purpose to do this? The point with Apache Kafka that it doesn't remove messages, so you are going to get all the records from the topic every time. Also there is no way on the consumer side to know that produce has sent a record to the topic. This is not what messaging middleware is for...

Comment: @cricket_007 yes , exactly. This topic specifically will not contain millions of records, it is a configuration topic, and as such I need to read the whole topic every time it is consumed.

Comment: The purpose is, and I appreciate its not what Kafka was designed for but its what I have been asked to implement is to use a compacted topic with 1 partition to hold a list of configurations.  This then needs to be called by a rest end point and it should display a full unique list of the configurations, the unique part is fine a java set sorts that, the issue i'm running into is when I implement this with a regular consumer, its incredibly slow as it has to initialize the consumer and reset the offset.  and with @Kafka listener it only displays the most recent message.

Comment: @ArtemBilan "_What is the business purpose to do this?_" isn't your problem. Every professional encounter problems and subjects that he has to resolve, and you are not here to class which ones are good subjects and which ones are bad. If he needs to read a topic from the beginning, he needs to do so, and that's all. Without your acknowledgment.

Answer (score 1):

> use a compacted topic with 1 partition to hold a list of configurations. This then needs to be called by a rest end point and it should display a full unique list of the configurations

The way you're supposed to implement this is using Kafka Streams and a KTable and settling up [interactive queries](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) behind your REST layer. Not a standard consumer that needs to rewind itself to get the most updated state of the system.

An example of this already exists in the Kafka Connect framework, where it has a config topic, and you can access only the most recent value of `GET /connectors/name/config`, and only if you restart it or scale to more instances, will it consumes all the messages again. The Schema Registry is also an example of this, and stores an internal Hashmap of all the schemas in the `_schemas` topic, and has a REST API for reads, inserts, deletes

Essentially, when you get a new configuration for a given key, you can either "replace" the old value for a given key with an entirely new one, or you can "merge" the old value with the new data, in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've ruled out Kafka streams, the overhead is too high for what I need it for 100-200 records max.  I've had a look at how its done in schema registry, it looks like it copies the topic to an in memory cache and updates it as new messages are added.  I think I will use this approach only i'll copy them to a h2 in mem db and then I can use standard spring crudrepository to interact with it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "overhead". One problem with storing locally in memory is that if you ever scale out your application, each instance only gets partial data. The schema registry only has a single partitioned topic, and only one eligible master that accepts requests, so it can avoid that problem. If you really want to copy that, that's where the true overhead comes from. I believe there's a Spring Kafka Streams wrapper, if you're talking about code

Answer (score 1):

Here how I will implement it. You need to implement `ConsumerSeekAware` interface and do some implementations on `onPartitionsAssigned` method. You can also make seekToBegining on demand if you send an environment variable while restarting your app. I haven't implemented it though!

```
@Service
@EnableKafka
public class Service implements ConsumerSeekAware {



    @KafkaListener(topics = "${topicName}", groupId = "${groupId}")
    public void listen(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts,
                       @Payload List<String> messageBatch
    ) {
            //do a bunch of stuff
    }



    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        String topic= Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty(TOPIC_NAME)).orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException("topicName needs to be set"));
        assignments.keySet().stream().filter(partition->topic.equals(partition.topic()))
                .forEach(partition -> callback.seekToBeginning(topic, partition.partition()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {}

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions 
          = @TopicPartition(topic = "test", partitionOffsets = {
          @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0")}),groupId = "foo",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listenAllMsg(@Payload String message,@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
    System.out.println(" all msg Received Messasge in group 'foo': " + message+"RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID - "+partition);

}
```

in kafka 2.3.1

Answer (score -1):

@Nimo1981 So this is an implementation with plain Java. I am unsure if it meets your needs. So basically I am commiting an offset of 0, (meaning , even if I read from Kafka topic, I go back to the offset that is at the beginning.) I am unsure if you have considered this implementation but please let me know if this is what you are looking for

Leave out the CommitCountObj. That is not needed for yours.
So by default the **offsetMap** will have the next offset record like this,

offsetMap.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                                new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() + 1, "some commit success message"));

but for your use case , I kind of modified, it works well when the consumer is not restarted

offsetMap.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                                new OffsetAndMetadata(0,"no commit done"));

```
public class KafkaConsumerClass {

    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(KafkaConsumerClass.class);
    private CommitCountClass commitCountobj = new CommitCountClass();

    public Consumer<String, List<FeedBackConsumerClass>> createConsumer() {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:7070,localhost:7072");
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, 50000);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "first_group-client1");
        // consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "first_group");
        // consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, KafkaConsumerInterceptor.class);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1500);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        return new KafkaConsumer<String, List<FeedBackConsumerClass>>(consumerProps);
    }

    public void consumeRecord() {
        log.info("Coming inside consumer consumer");
        ArrayList<String> topicList = new ArrayList<String>();
        topicList.add("topic1");
        commitCountobj.setCount(0);
        Consumer<String, List<FeedBackConsumerClass>> kafkaConsumer = createConsumer();
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topicList);
        log.info("after subscribing");

        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsetMap = new HashMap<>();

        while (true) {

            ConsumerRecords<String, List<FeedBackConsumerClass>> recordList = kafkaConsumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            // kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(kafkaConsumer.assignment());

            log.info("Inside while loop:" + recordList);
            if (!recordList.isEmpty()) {
                recordList.forEach(record -> {
                    int i = 0;
                    System.out.println(record.toString());
                    // we can make the call to the API here
                    // call the db here or any API and process the record
                    // then call the code to commit
                    // since the commit is switched off, it becomes a developers responsibility to do the auto commit
                    offsetMap.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                            new OffsetAndMetadata(0, "no metadata/offset commited"));
                    // here we are incrementing the offsetMap so that we are making sure we are storing the
                    // next set of offsets in the map
                    if (commitCountobj.getCount() % 1000 == 0) {
                        kafkaConsumer.commitAsync(offsetMap, new OffsetCommitCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets,
                                    Exception exception) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (exception != null) {
                                    // retry it now with a sync
                                    // possibility of error occuring here as well
                                    // so capture the exception and exit the consumer gracefully
                                    kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
                                    log.error(exception.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    commitCountobj.setCount(i++);
                });
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have not closed the consumer, but you could try to close the consumer after it reads, remember you need to have a mechasnim implemented to trigger the consumer every time when a producer produces a record because Apache Kafka doesnt do that on its own.

Comment: Remember closing and starting the consumer everytime is not recommended. And Kafka doesn't tend to create/restart/start a consumer everytime when a record is produced. That is never a use case that can be achieved only using Kafka. Also it is not recommend to restart/create new consumers for every new record produced because of the performance overhead. It can however guarantee that consumer consumes either from beginning or from the earliest offset commited, but it all depends on the use case.

Comment: Now if you do not wish to you use plain old Java, you could use springboot with it. I came across this solution and it worked like a charm- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352008/spring-kafka-how-to-read-one-topic-from-the-beginning-while-reading-another-o