# How to reset the offset value to re-read the kafka topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

There is a situation when **Consumer1** reads messages from a kafka topic. When connecting the second **Consumer2** with the same **groupId**, there is a rebalance of partitions.  Is it possible to somehow reset the **offset**, so that after the rebalance process, both **Consumers** read the topic from the beginning?

Comment: Have you tried to `seekToBeginning`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, No, I don't know kafka so deeply, how do I do this?

Comment: That is a method on a Consumer instance. See example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352008/spring-kafka-how-to-read-one-topic-from-the-beginning-while-reading-another-o

Answer (score 0):

I think as per your requirement you can set the offset value as **Earliest** , so that it can consumed from beginning.

For more details for offset you can visit this article which explains what value you can set offset value to [[https://dzone.com/articles/apache-kafka-consumer-group-offset-retention]](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-kafka-consumer-group-offset-retention)

Comment: `auto.offset.reset` only works for a non-existing consumer group

Answer (score 0):

Shut down all consumers in your consumer group then do this:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --group my-special-consumer --topic car-positions --reset-offsets --to-earliest
```

Comment: I didn't want to do it manually, I wanted do it from my java app:)